# Resizing webs on UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiwebview

In xcode 6, and IPhone6 or IPhone5 simulator or on my physical IPhone, Why uiwebview does not appear full page?. What does that make uiwebview to adapt the website to the size of IPhone?. If I open the page in the IPhone Safari the page looks good.

Comment: Please ass your initialisation for your UIWebView. Or UIWebView in your storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
self.view = self.webview;
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```